# scilab sending java main-class error and doesn't wanna work

Tags: java, ubuntu, scilab

scilab was working just fine 2 weeks ago but now after i updated software ubuntu if i try to open it nothing happens and if i try to open it using Terminal i get this error

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath (file:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.sys_paths
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Could not access to the Main Scilab Class:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.scilab.modules.localization.Messages.gettext(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.commons.xml.XConfiguration.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.core.Scilab.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2646)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1870)
    at org.scilab.modules.localization.MessagesJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more

Scilab cannot create Scilab Java Main-Class (we have not been able to find the main Scilab class. Check if the Scilab and thirdparty packages are available).
```

i tried reinstalling it and reinstalling java but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. After googling I found out that this bug was fixed in Scilab 6.0.2.

You can download it here:

https://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.2

Current version of Scilab, that you can get from

```
sudo apt-get scilab
```

is 6.0.1 (for me scilab-cli was working, but GUI was not)

Currently Scilab 6.0.2 works in GUI mode and CLI under Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. XCOS works too.

It is a little bit laggy after start, but it might be my setup.

Comment: Same problem with Scilab 6.1.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.